# How to Uninstall Python 3.6 safely and let 3.9 remain installed on my Mac big Sur especially the carshes

Tags: crash, python

Recently my Mac got updated to Big Sur and Pycharm and Python idle have stopped working : both crash. I have read Google but want a sure shot way to uninstall 3.6 and have only 3.9 remain installed. Also will the application programs I created with 3.6 be destroyed on removing 3.6? Or extended to 3.9?[image]
Another [image]
I won’t like to reinstall Mac or something just need a working procedure for the same. My Mac has many apps loaded on it

Error stacktrace:

dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Reason: image not found

Hoping for early reply

Please keep in mind I dont have a great understanding of Apple products so hoping for educative answers to solve my problems

Comment: How have you installed python? BigSur does not have python3 by default which would give a similar error to what you show - you need Xcode command line tools for Apple supplied one but the best advice is to use another python install.

Comment: I installed python from their website with idle then I installed pycharms with python 3.9 and at that I started getting a crash every time I run a .py file and it also errors that 3.6 is not found though it’s there in library in Apple. Also the idle has version 2 FYI. Please provide a time tested solution so that I don’t mess up my system. Thanks!

Comment: I installed python 3.9 using home brew

Comment: Have you configured PyCharm as described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: I tried adding 3.9 as Interprtetor in PyCharms but few scripts run while few gives error and crash(not completely but the crash message comes). Looks like somehow the location of Py 3.6 was removed but projects still have reference to them. Also 3.6 does show in Library alongwith 3.9. What to do?

Comment: Any other helpful direction? How Should I try with XCode?

Comment: Aivar's answer was good: "Have you configured PyCharm as described here: jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html?" It didn't stop the crash which is still there but at least I got it working with Py 3.9. many thanks!

Comment: Any info on the crash-how it can be rectified?

Comment: It would be great to have a time tested but simple way to rectify the crash. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last the crash does not happen anymore! I followed the "Setting the default interpreter" for New Projects Settings from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#default-interpreter, selected 3.9 venv as default interpreter and this fixed the issue.